# Using variable as database column in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How do I use a variable field to access data? I do not know which column I will be searching which is why this is neccessary

```
db.tbl.FirstOrDefault(r => r.(variable) == "live");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try dynamic linq:

It allows you to write queries like:

```
db.tbl.Where("some_column_name = live").FirstOrDefault();
```

See: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: What about for trying to access the db result like                                     
        var email = record.("var")

Comment: I am not sure but I think you can use `Select` the same way. You might need to check the return type though: `.Select("PhoneNumber").FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Says is a enumerable.select is a method not valid in the given context

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to select just one or a few properties which map to columns you can do the following;

```
var emails = context.Person.Select(x => new 
{
    x.Emails
});
```

This returns an collection of object with Email property.

Hope this helps

Comment: It is the actual column that is variable though, Emails in your example